# The shared library "Cloud Music Library" is not responding. (503)

Tags: icloud

[image]

What is an error? I cannot log in to itunes store at all. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210759/85275

"According to [Apple Support System Status](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/), now, the iTunes Store Service may be unavailable for some users."

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to sign out through the **Store** menu on the top, and then signing back in, then restart iTunes after a few seconds. It could be coincidence, but that did the trick for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This works....was signed in and did not know it...after the iTunes stored deleted all the "genius" recommendations (hang in there.it can take a while) everything popped right back up..many thanks for a short, precise, fix.