# My app store can't dowload some apps or update

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I can't update WhatsApp, Snapchat and many other apps in my system, that is 9.0.1.

I tried to change date and time, turn off my iPhone and sign out.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Support System Status](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/), at the time of writing 2015/10/13, the iTunes Store Service may be unavailable for some users.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to iOS 9.0.2. It's all bug fixes and it might fix your problem.